# Как вывести Hex из 2's complement силами Python?

Tags: python

Есть такая задача:
Есть ID-шник: 10088363095792553999
Его hex очень даже легко найти: 0x8C0110C901E0100F. Получить эти данные тоже легко силами python:

```
value = 10088363095792553999
hex_value = hex(value)  # 0x8c0110c901e0100f
```

Онлайн калькулятор подсказывает, что из Hex'a его 2's complement будет "-8358380977916997617". Не знаю, можно ли тут выкладывать ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, но конвертер легко найти в гугле по запросу "Hexadecimal to Decimal converter".
Есть пробел: я не знаю, как питоном вывести из Хекса его 2's complement.
НО! Что **самое тут нужное, это обратная операция**: необходимо из значения его 2's complement (-8358380977916997617) силами Python получить обратно его хекс - 0x8c0110c901e0100f. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос уже довольно подробно раскрыт [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python).

Приведу рабочее решение для вашего примера:

```
def twos_complement(n, w):
    if n & (1 << (w - 1)):
        n = n - (1 << w)
    return n


def int2hex(number, bits):
    if number < 0:
        return hex((1 << bits) + number)
    return hex(number)


hex_value = '0x8c0110c901e0100f'
value = twos_complement(int(hex_value, 16), 64)
print(value)  # -8358380977916997617

print(int2hex(value, 64))  # 0x8c0110c901e0100f
```

Comment: Не выходит. Калькулятор говорит (и именно эти значения я имею на практике), что если взять хекс «0x8c0110c901e0100f», то его Decimal number это «10088363095792553999», а его Decimal from signed 2's complement это «-8358380977916997617». 

И вот нужно из последнего, отрицательного, значения вывести первое (хекс). Или второе (Decimal number которое) . Только не калькулятором, а силами питона. 

Либо же взять Decimal number (10088363095792553999) и вывести из него Decimal from signed 2's complement которое отрицательное (-8358380977916997617).

Comment: @DamienDamieAmfiet я просто опечатался в количестве бит, поправил.